# Passport LocalStrategy Not working on Two login system

Tags: node.js, passport-local

So In My Project I am using two Login System. One for Admin i.e Seperate and other for users.
Already implemented Login System of Admin with The help of Passport.
Now when I am using same concept In user login system at that time Its not working. I mean It affect my admin Login. 
My code is

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!user){
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
        }
        User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(isMatch){
                return done(null, user);
            }else{
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid Credential, please check carefully...!'})
            }
        });
    });
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect: '/user/login',
    badRequestMessage: 'Field cannot be blank.!!', //missing credentials
    failureFlash: true
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    req.flash('success_msg', 'Welcome ' + req.user.name);
    res.redirect('/user/dashboard');
  });
```

I thought that LocalStrategy generate error so I aslo used basicStrategy but then My Admin Login Works Perfectly like earlier but my user login not works. Every time it Says Basic Realm = "Users".
Any Help will be Appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Its not on Local or Basic Strategy. It Totally depends on passport.serializeUser and deserializeUser.
We have to send User data, not user id on serializeUser. And on deserializeUser, we have to pick some uniqueness and then according to condition your query run. Actually, the deserializeUser function can handle Only one DB at a time of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way. It creates two schemas one for admin and one or user. Accordingly create two local strategies by naming them and then we can serialize and deserialize the user based on their credentials. Hope this helps :)

```
app.get("/register", function(req, res){
    res.render("reg")
})

app.post("/register", function(req, res){
    var type = req.body.type
    if(type=="student"){
    var newUser = new Student({
        username: req.body.username,
        gender: req.body.gender,
        rollnumber: req.body.rollnumber,
        dob: req.body.dob,
        email: req.body.email,
        type: req.body.type,
        password: req.body.password
    })

    req.checkBody('username','UserName is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('rollnumber','Roll Number is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email Invalid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password','Password is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password1','Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if(errors){
        res.render('Sregister', {errors: errors});
    }else{
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err,  salt){
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash){
            if(!err){
                newUser.password = hash;
            }
            newUser.save(function(err){
                if(!err){
                    console.log("success in reg");
                    res.redirect("/student/login")
                }
            })
        })
    })
    }}
    else if(type=="teacher"){
        var newUser = new Teacher({
        username: req.body.username,
        gender: req.body.gender,
        rollnumber: req.body.rollnumber,
        dob: req.body.dob,
        email: req.body.email,
        type: req.body.type,
        password: req.body.password
    })

    req.checkBody('username','UserName is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('rollnumber','Roll Number is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email Invalid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password','Password is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password1','Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if(errors){
        res.render('Sregister', {errors: errors});
    }else{

             bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err,  salt){
                 bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash){
                    if(!err){
                         newUser.password = hash;
                  }
                        newUser.save(function(err){
                     if(!err){
                         console.log("success in reg");
                         res.redirect("/teacher/login")
                }
            })
        })
    })
    }}
})

//strategies

passport.use('student', new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done){
    var query = {username: username};
    Student.findOne(query, function(err, student){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!student){
            return done(null, false);
        }
        bcrypt.compare(password,student.password, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(isMatch)
                return done(null, student);
            else
                return done(null,false);
        })
    })
}))

passport.use('teacher', new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done){
    var query = {username: username};
    Teacher.findOne(query, function(err, teacher){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!teacher){
            console.log("no teach")
            return done(null, false);
        }
        bcrypt.compare(password,teacher.password, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(isMatch)
                return done(null, teacher);
            else
                return done(null,false);
        })
    })
}))

//serialize deserizlize

passport.serializeUser(function (entity, done) {
    done(null, { id: entity.id, type: entity.type });
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
    switch (obj.type) {
        case 'student':
            Student.findById(obj.id)
                .then(user => {
                    if (user) {
                        done(null, user);
                    }
                    else {
                        done(new Error('user id not found:' + obj.id, null));
                    }
                });
            break;
        case 'teacher':
            Teacher.findById(obj.id)
                .then(device => {
                    if (device) {
                        done(null, device);
                    } else {
                        done(new Error('device id not found:' + obj.id, null));
                    }
                });
            break;
        default:
            done(new Error('no entity type:', obj.type), null);
            break;
    }
});
//login routes

app.get("/student/login", function(req, res){
    res.render("slogin")
})

app.get("/teacher/login", function(req, res){
    res.render("tlogin")
})

app.post('/student/login', 
  passport.authenticate('student', { successRedirect: '/student/home', failureRedirect: '/student/login' }));

app.post('/teacher/login', 
  passport.authenticate('teacher', { successRedirect: '/teacher/home', failureRedirect: '/teacher/login' }));


app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("home");  
})

app.get("/student/home", function(req, res){
  res.send("hi student")
})

app.get("/teacher/home", function(req, res){
  res.send("hi teacher")  
})
```